# Pushing details view controller on list view controller presented in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have UIPageViewController which is added to UINavigationController after pressing given button.

UIPageViewController contains other controllers representing 2 pages. Pages are lists of items which can be clicked to present details of clicked item. Details page has to be "pushed" on list page.

I tried to "push" details page by calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` of UIPageViewController however after doing so I have original list view which was on second page as first page and details view as second page.

I also update data source so that methods `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` reflect new views organization.

But this doesn't work.

Do you know what can be the reason of this ?

My second though was is to use separate UINavigationController for every page, as I understand there are no objections to use more then one UINavigationController in the application ?

Comment: I'd go with the second approach. It's safe using multiple `UINavigationController` objects and should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alexbumbu is right the best way is not to over-combine with `UIPageViewController` and use separate `UINavigationController`s for every page stack flow.

That was my choice